# C++ Bitwise Operator Understanding Code

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

```
a &= ~(1 << 10);
```

Does the code above actually mean:

```
a &= (0 << 10);
```

Comment: No, your second code is equal to `a = 0;`

Comment: Why not write a program to find out?

Comment: No, it means `a &= ~(1 << 10);`... duh?

Comment: The code will clear bit 10 in a. Assuming 32 bit int: (1 << 10) = 0x00000400, and ~(1 << 10) = 0xfffffbff .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~` is bitwise inversion (take every 1 and turn it into 0, every 0 into 1), so if you have `x = 0b0100` (assume 4 bit integers for a second), then `~x == 0b1011`. `<<` is "shift this to the left", so '(1 << 2) == 0b0100`.